# Show that the restriction of $f$ to any straight line through $B$ has a local minimum in $B$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

I have the following problem:

> We have the function: $f(x,y)=(x^2+y^2-6x)\cdot (\frac{1}{8}y^2-x)$
>
> We also have the point $B=(0,0)$.
>
> Show that the restriction of $f$ to any straight line through $B$ has a local minimum in $B$. Is this enough to prove that $f$ has a local minimum in $B$? Does $f$ actually have local minimum in $B$?

Okay, so I am having some trouble with this. I have found the partiel derivatives for $f$.

$f'_x=(2x-6) \cdot (\frac{y^2}{8}-x)-x^2-y^2+6x$

$f'_y=2y(\frac{y^2}{8}-x)+\frac{(x^2+y^2-6x)y}{4}$

Inserting $(0,0$ into both $f'_x$ and $f'_y$ yields:

$f'_x(0,0)=0$

$f'_y(0,0)=0$

Here, I just showed that $B$ is a stationary point, but I don't really know how to continue from here, and show that any straight line has a local minimum in $B$.

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight lines through $(0, 0)$ take the form
$$y = mx$$
for some $m \in \Bbb{R}$, when not vertical. When vertical, the equation becomes
$$x = 0.$$
This means two cases. For the first case, substitute $(x, y) = (x, mx)$ into $f(x, y)$:
\begin{align*}
f(x, mx) &= (x^2 + m^2 x^2 - 6x)\cdot\left(\frac{1}{8}m^2x^2 - x\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{8}m^2(m^2 + 1)x^4 - \left(1 + \frac{7}{4}m^2\right)x^3 + 6x^2 
\end{align*}
Let the above function of $x$ be $g(x)$. Now, it's a one variable function, and we can perform the usual tests to check for local minima. For example, we can differentiate:
\begin{align*}
g'(x) &= \frac{1}{2}m^2(m^2 + 1)x^3 - 3\left(1 + \frac{7}{4}m^2\right)x^2 + 12x \\
g''(x) &= \frac{3}{2}m^2(m^2 + 1)x^2 - 6\left(1 + \frac{7}{4}m^2\right)x + 12.
\end{align*}
Note that $g'(0) = 0$, so we have a stationary point, and $g''(0) = 12 > 0$, hence we have a local minimum.

For the second case, we can also consider $f(x, y)$ along the line $x = 0$, i.e. $f(0, y)$, but I'll leave that to you.

However, as mathcounterexamples.net points out, this is not a local minimum.

Comment: When I work on the case for $x=0$, with $f(0,y)$ I get that $f(0,y)=\frac{1}{8}y^4$. Let's say $h(y)=\frac{1}{8}y^4$ When differentiating, I still find that $h'(0)=0$ but I also get $h''(0)=0$. Does that mean that vertical lines doesn't have local minimum in $B$?

Comment: No, the second derivative just means that that the second derivative test has failed. Indeed, $h(y) = \frac{1}{8}y^4$ does have a local minimum, which can be ascertained by the first derivative test: $h'(y) = \frac{1}{2}y^3$, which is is positive when $y > 0$ and negative when $y < 0$.

Comment: Alright, I see. But can I ask one more thing. You say that (0,0) is not a global minimum, while mathcounterexamples.net says that (0,0) is not a local minimum? Who is right?

Comment: @Carl Not me. I meant to say local minimum. (Of course, this does mean it isn't a global minimum either.)

Comment: Okay, so it does not have local minimum. How can I justify this claim, because I don't quite understand what mathcounterexamples.net is telling me.

Comment: @Carl mathcounterexamples.net is evaluating the function over a different curve (instead of a straight line), specifically the parabola $x = y^2/6$. If $(0, 0)$ were a local minimum, then it should be a local minimum along every possible curve going through $(0, 0)$. Mce.net is providing an example of a curve along which the function is a strict maximum. They're giving us a set of points along which the function lies below our supposed local minimum, which come as close as you like to $(0, 0)$. This contradicts local minimality.

Comment: Okay, so because $(0,0)$ is a maximum for $f$ when $x=y^2/6$ then it can't be a local minimum? Am I understanding it right?

Comment: The only way that a point can be both a local minimum and a local maximum is if it is locally constant. That is, the function takes the value $f(0,0)$ at $(0, 0)$, and every point within a small distance of $(0, 0)$. What mce.net shows is slightly stronger than just a local maximum: there are points whose function value are **strictly less** than $f(0, 0)$, no matter how close you come to $(0, 0)$. So, no matter how small the neighbourhood of $(0, 0)$, $f(0, 0)$ is not the minimum value in that neighbourhood. That, by definition, means $(0, 0)$ is not a local minimum.

Comment: @Carl So, while you're on the right track here, it's almost but not **quite** enough to just show a local maximum along a curve.

Comment: Thank you for this. This really helped me through understanding this problem.

Comment: @Carl No worries!

Answer (score 1):

This map doesn’t have a local minimum at $(0,0)$. To see it, you can look at

$$f(y^2/6,y)=-y^4/(36 \cdot 24) <0$$

This is a strange example of a map having a minimum at $(0,0)$ for all lines passing through the origin but not a minimum at the origin as a map of two variables.

See [here](https://www.mathcounterexamples.net/no-minimum-at-the-origin-but-a-minimum-among-all-lines/) for another example.

Comment: I'm not sure how I should be able to see that the map doesn't have a minimum at $(0,0)$ by looking at $f(y^2/6,y)$. Could you elaborate please?